# Is it possible for view to drop shadow on iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I have code that worked on iOS6:

```
[v.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[v.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[v.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0., 2.)];
```

On iOS7 it doen't.

Is it possible for view to have shadows on iOS7 in some simple way like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Check that the code is getting executed and that v isn't `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made very stupid mistake: I just located view in Document Outline to the first position, so shadow is overlapped by next views... I move it to the last position and now everything is fine. I do not know if it would be useful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the `masksToBounds` property of your view’s layer is set to `NO`. If it is set to `YES` anything that is outside the bounds rectangle of that layer (like the shadow) will not be drawn.

Also check the `clipsToBounds` property of your superviews. If it is set to `YES` any parts of subviews that are outside the bounds rectangle of a view will not be drawn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I've made very stupid mistake: I just located view in Document Outline to the first position, so shadow is overlapped by next views... I move it to the last position and now everything is fine. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine in iOS 7 I checked it with my NavigationBar title View. You better check your reset of code. And post some more code so we can check is there any issue some where else.

```
[self.navigationItem.titleView.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [self.navigationItem.titleView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
```